# Laravel 403 forbidden on custom Request validation

Tags: php, laravel

I've followed the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

I created a custom request StoreName

```
php artisan make:request StoreName
```

Then added the following validation rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|min:4'
    ];
}
```

Then as per the documentation type-hinted this in my controller:

```
public function store(StoreName $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

However, when I send a post request to this endpoint I'm returned a `403` from Laravel. When I remove the StoreName custom validation and simply type-hint the standard Laravel `Illuminate\Http\Request` the request works fine (after removing the validated() method obviously).

So the 403 is coming from my custom validation request and I have no idea why? I've checked the file permissions on the StoreName.php file and they are the same as every other file in the project.

I'm using `php artisan serve` for my development server so no funky Apache/Nginx configs overwriting things either. All other endpoints work apart from this one when the custom validation request is applied.

What could the problem be?

---

EDIT:

It's probably worth noting I've not changed the default authorize() method Laravel generates in the new custom request validation either:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your Custom request class you've got a method like this:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true; // this is false by default which means unauthorized 403
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it, it seems counter-intuitive to me setting it to true. Setting it to true reads you are checking if the user is authorized rather than false not checking.

Comment: You should use a Policy here instead of just `true`, `false` I just showed you where the 403 comes from.

Comment: so this answer helps?

Comment: @Muabazalm yeah this answers fixes the issue I can't accept the answer for another 10minutes. As above though it seems counter-intuitive to check if the user is authorized to make the request, surely being set to false would mean not to check if they are authorized, that's how it reads anyway.

Comment: @twigg if you ask the question as "Am I authorized to perform this request?", then it reads well in my mind. So if you use a policy here it will become `$this->authorize('edit', Post::class);` which means am I authorized to perform edit on the post .. true means yes go ahead, false means 403, forbidden.

Comment: @nakov yeah that makes sense when worded like that

Comment: Jeez, I lost a lot of time after I tried to start using FormRequests because of this

Answer (score 1):

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

on your requests make change false to true

```
    public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```