# How do i solve 403 post request in axios?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've been working on Laravel and VueJs and I'm using AXIOS to save data to MySQL however upon using Post I've got 403 forbidden

I'm using Windows 10 64bit and Laragon

```
 <script>import axios from 'axios';
export default{
    data() {
        return{
            form:{
                job_name: null,
                job_description: null,
                vacants: 0
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        submit() {
        axios.post('/job_postings', this.form)
        .then(function (response) {
            alert('success')
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert('something went wrong')
        });
        }
    }
}
```

```
Route::resource('/job_postings',JobPostingController::class);

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\JobPostingRequest;
use App\Models\JobPosting;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobPostingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('job_posting.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(JobPostingRequest $jobPostingRequest, JobPosting $jobPosting)
    {
        $posting = $jobPosting::create($jobPostingRequest->all());
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Job Posting has been sucessfully saved', 'data' => $posting]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\JobPosting  $jobPosting
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(JobPosting $jobPosting)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\JobPosting  $jobPosting
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(JobPosting $jobPosting)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\JobPosting  $jobPosting
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, JobPosting $jobPosting)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\JobPosting  $jobPosting
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(JobPosting $jobPosting)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

error in dev console

```
   {data: {…}, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "/job_postings", method: "post", data: "{"job_name":"test","job_description":"","vacants":0}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {message: "This action is unauthorized.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException", file: "C:\laragon\www\lara-vue\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php", line: 367, trace: Array(40)}
headers: {cache-control: "no-cache, private", connection: "close", content-type: "application/json", date: "Thu, 11 Feb 2021 14:33:57 GMT, Thu, 11 Feb 2021 14:33:57 GMT", host: "127.0.0.1:8000", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
__proto__: Object
```

I've been working on Laravel and VueJs and I'm using AXIOS to save data to MySQL however upon using Post I've got 403 forbidden

I'm using Windows 10 64bit and Laragon

Comment: Can you share some code with us so we can see what is happening in your request?

Comment: share some code, it is most probably something with permission

Comment: @JeffreyJadePortillo Could you please share route `job_postings`?

Comment: code has been updated.

Comment: Did you use any `middleware`?

Comment: If possible, could you please share content of `JobPostingController`?

Comment: No I did not use any middleware

Comment: Could you please share `construct` function of `JobPostingController`?

Comment: Check the `authorize` function in the JobPostingRequest class, if it returning false, change to true and try again

Comment: it works guys I just change the authorize from false to true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 403 forbidden on custom Request validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235420/laravel-403-forbidden-on-custom-request-validation)

Comment: Ok, I mark your question as a duplicate of that other one, because it could be answered with the same answer of that question. Happy code!

Comment: Thanks, guys happy coding